# Drupal module names missing

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

Here's a new one... I have a site running Drupal 5.  I'm going to upgrade it to 6, and I just noticed that there are some blank lines on the modules page.  The first four modules listed in the "Other" section have no names, just checkboxes.  (Actually one of them also has the text "Required by: Forum (disabled), Tracker (disabled)".)  The fourth module is actually turned on, but I have no idea what it is.

I just installed a fresh install of D5 just to see what the first four "Other" modules should be, and they're blank!  So I'm guessing this is some sort of incompatibility with PH5.3

Has anybody else seen this?

Comment: off-topic, but you know Drupal 7 is almost ready for release (it's at release candidate stage, so final release is imminent). You may want to consider skipping past D6 entirely to save yourself another upgrade at a later date.

Comment: The [Drupal system requirements page](http://drupal.org/requirements) has detailed info about compatibility with different PHP versions. Drupal 6 did originally have issues with PHP 5.3, but this should have been dealt with since v6.14. However, that doesn't necessarily apply to non-core modules.

Comment: @Spudley Ha ha, I was waiting for the D7 comments. :-)  Yeah, I know.  I'll probably hold off for a while on adopting D7.  I actually haven't done a major version upgrade yet.  I assumed that I'd have to go through D6... can you bypass a major version?

Comment: Yep, I did indeed find it was a PHP5.3 issue.  I had to put quotes around some lines in four different modules/*.info files.  I've been banging my head up against this for some time, and of course, as soon as I post my question here, the answer became apparent.  Thanks for the replies!

(BTW, they were actually core modules, but because they had formatting issues in *.info files, D didn't know where to put them.)

Comment: @Mark: No you can't skip a major version if you plan to go through the upgrade process (see here: http://drupal.org/upgrade). But if you want to try D7 anyway, you can download the current RC1 from here: http://drupal.org/project/drupal

Comment: @spudley: although D7 will be released soon, you really need to be an expert if you want to use it for something complex. There are still quite a few strange bugs floating around.

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't launch a production site on D7 yet, or even for quite a while after it is released. In my opinion D6 is still the more solid and better supported option at the moment, even if D7 is better in other ways.

Comment: @googletorp: not just a few. approximately 1900 bugs, to be more precise: http://drupal.org/project/issues/drupal?text=&status=Open&priorities=All&categories=bug&version=7.x&component=All

Comment: @berkes The number of bugs is in itself not interesting, but the number of critical/major bugs can be. For reference, there is aprox 1900 bugs reported for D6.

Comment: @googletorp I disagree. I have just built my fourth Drupalsite, and all four of them had trouble with one of the reported bugs. No mayor issues, but *for me and my clients* they were showstoppers. Critical/mayors are marked as such for *Drupal*, but your project may grind to a halt over into a *minor*, making it critical not for Drupal, but for you. 1900 bugs are just a big lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP5.3 has issues with many Drupal5 .info files. You must put quotes around all the descriptive lines. See here for more info http://drupal.org/node/722430